# Rbenv Doesn't Work Trying to Install Latest Version of Ruby

Tags: shell, homebrew, rbenv

I tried updating my Ruby to the current version 2.6.3 in the terminal. When the installation is complete and I check my version it says it's still 2.3.3.

I've tried re-installing 2 times already, both times have not succeded.

```
Installed ruby-2.6.3 to /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`README.md`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos) from the project's repo. Your rbenv is not initialized.

Put the following lines into your shell. `.bash_profile` for Bash, `.zshrc` for ZSH.

```sh
if command -v rbenv &>/dev/null; then
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

After which, restart your shell.

References

- [Install with Homebrew on macOS](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos)